# What are the Amazon Order API throttling rates

Tags: amazon-mws

I am unable to find any documentation on the MWS Orders API throttling rates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: The PDF files that used to be linked here seem to be gone. Links now go to the new HTML docs

The throttling algorithm is described in the [MWS Developer Guide](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Throttling.html). The request quotas vary between APIs and calls.

The Products API has a separate page describing quotas:

- [MWS Products API Reference](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_Throttling.html)

All other APIs list quotas and recovery rates in their "Description" section of each call:

- [MWS Orders API Reference - Example ListOrders](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html) - Note there also is an older version of this API
- [MWS Sellers API Reference - Example ListMarketplaceParticipations](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/sellers/Sellers_ListMarketplaceParticipations.html)
- [MWS Reports API Reference - Example RequestReport](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_RequestReport.html)
- [MWS Feeds API Reference - Example SubmitFeed](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html)
- [MWS Inbound Shipment API Reference - Example GetInboundGuidanceForSKU](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_GetInboundGuidanceForSKU.html)
- [MWS Inventory API Reference - Example ListInventorySupply](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inventory/FBAInventory_ListInventorySupply.html)
- [MWS Outbound Shipment API Reference - Example GetFulfillmentPreview](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_outbound/FBAOutbound_GetFulfillmentPreview.html)
- [MWS Finances API Reference - Example ListFinancialEventGroups](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/finances/Finances_ListFinancialEventGroups.html)
- [MWS Merchant Fulfillment API Reference - Example GetEligibleShippingServices](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/merch_fulfill/MerchFulfill_GetEligibleShippingServices.html)
- [MWS Recommendations API Reference - Example GetLastUpdatedTimeForRecommendations](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/recommendations/Recommendations_GetLastUpdatedTimeForRecommendations.html)
- [MWS Subscriptions API Reference - Example RegisterDestination](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/subscriptions/Subscriptions_RegisterDestination.html)

Comment: Oh my - i saw the products api which differs and was looking for the table that used to be on last page of orders. A little line below that i did not see

Comment: Have any idea about MWS Finances API Reference or any other documents...

Comment: @JayVenkat I was unable to find a MWS Finances API Reference as a PDF file, but it is available online here http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/finances/index.html - Throttling rates are listed below each API call's description section.

Answer (score 2):

The throttling algorithm is described in the Orders API Documentation.

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_Overview.html

The request quotas vary between APIs and calls.

Here are some common calls and their relevant throttle limit as of December 2016.

> The ListOrders and ListOrdersByNextToken operations together share a
>   maximum request quota of six and a restore rate of one request every
>   minute.
>
> The GetOrder operation has a maximum request quota of six and a
>   restore rate of one request every minute.
>
> The ListOrderItems and ListOrderItemsByNextToken operations together
>   share a maximum request quota of 30 and a restore rate of one request
>   every two seconds.